# Delphi XE8 styles do not work with TFrames? How to fix this?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, tframe

I use `TFrames`. I make them dynamically by adding them to the Form window. I chose the style called "Glow" (others also). I launched the program and the style works only on the main Form window, they do not work on the controls `TFrame`. Why?

I tried to add: `TStyleManager.SetStyle` for the Frame Form but with no effect.

Comment: Please provide an MCVE so that we know what you are doing and can reproduce.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/rKF7HKj.png

Comment: No. Please don't post off site links. Please post an MCVE as I requested.

Comment: @David Heffernan what do you mean? Can you explain MCVE shortcut?

Comment: Please use a websearch to find out what it means.

Comment: ah, so you mean an example code?

Comment: Yes. One that can be compiled if at all possible, and one that is minimal.

Comment: So you never used FRAMES in Delphi? http://pastebin.com/CW5wAAHW also you can add an frame manually, drag & drop, same effect and same problem with skin. Rest things you know, i have used one skin (project options menu) and thats all. I have checked which skin is used on Frame and same as main Form, so Skin should work but do not work. Maybe frames are bugged in delphi? If you want to add an Frame t your new project, use File -> New... -> Other -> VCL Frame

Comment: Please edit the question to include thee mcve.

Comment: The bug is really common, @David. I've also met it on XE5 (FMX Metropolis project). Moreover. It appears irregularly. If you open another form in the project that contains a control with the same style it is displayed properly. when you open (without terminating the current project) the faulty frame-containing form it starts showing conrols with proper style as well. In my case manual explict runtime setting of styles can help but not in all cases (for instance with odd TabItems only). It seems, that it appears in scroll forms (with HorzScrollBar and Form.Width>Screen.Width)

Comment: I spend quite a lot of time answering questions here. I know how it works. Make an MCVE, and you'll get good answers.

Comment: @asd-tm thanks. So what should I do? (details?)

Comment: You say "I make them dynamically by adding them to the Form window" and what David is asking is for you to show us this code so that we may know what's wrong about it.

Comment: I have not found the answer. Add details, requested by @David-Heffernan.

Comment: If you allow me to use answer field I shall explain how to reproduce it in a minute-two

Comment: @asd-tm and David Heffernan maybe i found bug (not sure). Probably once I set Frame Form Color and restore clBtnFace and maybe that is a bug. How to "delete" Color? Maybe delphi remember "he changed color manually so he dont want a Style on this Frame form window"?

Comment: @asd-tm btw. now im sure, the bug is Form Color, i have added new Frame and run application, Style was OK, and then i have changed Frame Form Color to random color and restore default color (color form field: ctrl + v, clBtnFace) and then i run program again and I saw BUG lol, so delphi is retarded? and he remember change of frame form color property and he making a bug... Wtf? Its stupid. How to "reset" Frame Form Color property other than manually ctrl + v? (because manually color change will make a bug)

Comment: so problem solved. Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this bug. If you will change `Frame Form Color` property manually, it will make a bug. You must select your `Frame` and go to `properties` and turn on the `ParentBackgroud` field (choose true) and you can also turn on the `ParentColor` too. Now `Styles` must work.

Comment: Please, add details of what you've done and what was actually the issue to help the community.

Comment: So as I said, if user will add TFrame (File -> New... -> Other -> VCL Frame) and then if he will change the Color Form (i mean that TFrame Form), then it will make a bug, Styles will not work for this Frame. To fix that, just set the "True" of ParentBackground (property of Form in TFrame window) etc. Now you understand? Color makes a bug, if you never change Form Color then you do not have to worry about. Just changing Form Color == Bug, and you know now how to fix it, just set the true ParentBackground of Form, thats all. Btw. my EN is poor, but i dont h've time now to use google translate

Comment: Mohammad, @David-Heffernan, I was writing my comments on alike problems in FMX projects. Unfortunately, this solution does not suit these cases as FMX TFrame ascendants do not have such property. The bug appears without setting any colors manually.

Comment: On your form, set the parent of that frame to have DoubleBuffered = fasle;   Man! Embarcadero will never ever fix the skins (styles)!